# Download Starting again in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, download

I am making a multi downloader using AsyncTask and arrayList.I want my android application to download videos in the background of my app. That's why I have created an application class and initialized my download arraylist there. My download listview is adding new items perfectly but when a new item is added, the previous item whether it is completely downloaded or partially downloaded starts getting downloading again.

Here is my application class:

```
public class GlobalDownload extends Application {


    private List<DownloadInfo> downloadinfo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        downloadinfo = new ArrayList<DownloadInfo>();


    }


    public List<DownloadInfo> getDownloadInfo(){
        return downloadinfo;
    }
    public String getDownloadStates()
    {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Here is my class where listview is getting populated:

```
public class DownloadScreen extends Activity implements {
  ListView listView;

    Animation animationslidedown;
    Animation animationslideup;
    TextView textView2;

    ImageView menu;
    ImageView menuicon1;
    String text="";
    List<DownloadInfo> downloadInfo;
     static final int REQUEST = 1;
    public static String f_type;
    public static Integer result;
    DownloadInfoArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download_layout);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloadListView);
        String file_name=getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE_NAME");



        String file_type=getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE_TYPE").toString();
        Log.e("file_type", "" + file_type);

        if(file_type.equals("video/mp4"))
        {
            f_type="mp4";
        }
        else if(file_type.equals("video/webm"))
        {
            f_type="webm";
        }
        else if(file_type.equals("video/x-flv"))
        {
            f_type="flv";
        }
        else if(file_type.equals("video/3gpp"))
        {
            f_type="3gpp";
        }



        GlobalDownload downloadList = ((GlobalDownload)getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList downloadState = (ArrayList) downloadList.getDownloadInfo();

        Log.e("NAME", "" + file_name);

        String file_url=getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE_URL");
        Log.e("URL", "" + file_url);
        String file_size=getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE_SIZE");
        Log.e("SIZE", "" + file_size);
        Log.e("TYPE", file_type.toString());
        downloadState.add(new DownloadInfo(file_name,file_url,file_size,f_type.toString()));

        listView.setAdapter(new DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.downloadListView, downloadState));
    }

}
```

Here are my AsyncTask activity and ArrayAdapeter Activity:

```
public class FileDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
   // private static final String    TAG = FileDownloadTask.class.getSimpleName();
    final DownloadInfo  mInfo;
    TextView display;
    public int progress;
    public  String encodedurl;



    DownloadInfoArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    public FileDownloadTask(DownloadInfo info) {
        mInfo = info;

    }

     @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mInfo.setProgress(values[0]);
        mInfo.setFilePercent(values[0]);
        ProgressBar bar = mInfo.getProgressBar();


        if (bar != null) {
            bar.setProgress(mInfo.getProgress());

        }


    }



    @Override

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count;

       if(mInfo.getDownloadState()!= DownloadInfo.DownloadState.COMPLETE)
       {
            try {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                System.out.println("Downloading");
//

                URL url = new URL(mInfo.getFileUrl().toString());
                Log.e("URL", "" + url);
                HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                Log.e("connection", " " + 0);

                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                Log.e("length", "" + lenghtOfFile);
                //input stream to read file - with 8k buffer

                // Output stream to write file
                File rootdirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "Youtube Videos");
                if (!rootdirectory.exists()) {
                    rootdirectory.mkdirs();
                }

                String nameoffile = mInfo.getFilename() + "." + mInfo.getFileType();
                File file = new File(rootdirectory, nameoffile);
                file.createNewFile();
                Log.e("name of file", "" + nameoffile);


                mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    progress = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                    publishProgress(progress);
                    Log.e("PROGRESS", "" + mInfo.getFileType() + progress);
                    mInfo.setFilePercent(progress);



                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
                Log.e("Download Complete", "" + 0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.COMPLETE);

       }


        return progress;
    }




    protected void onPostExecute(Integer progress) {
        mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.COMPLETE);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
    }



}
```

Here is my Adapter class from which AsyncTask is called

```
public class DownloadInfoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DownloadInfo> {
    public static TextView progpercent;

    public static Integer result;


    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        Button button;
        DownloadInfo info;
        TextView size;
        TextView prog;
        public TextView progpercent;
    }


    private static final String TAG = DownloadInfoArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                    List<DownloadInfo> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);



    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;


        final DownloadInfo info = getItem(position);



        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(null == row) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_download_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileName);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
            holder.size=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileSize);
            holder.progpercent=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileProgress);


            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
         }

        holder.textView.setText(info.getFilename());
        holder.progressBar.setProgress(info.getProgress());
        holder.progressBar.setMax(100);
        holder.size.setText(info.getFileSize());

        info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);

        info.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.QUEUED);

        FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(info);
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);



        return row;
    }



}
```

Here is my List Activity

```
public class DownloadInfo
{
private final static String TAG = DownloadInfo.class.getSimpleName();
public enum DownloadState {
    NOT_STARTED,
    QUEUED,
    DOWNLOADING,
    COMPLETE
}
private volatile DownloadState mDownloadState = DownloadState.NOT_STARTED;
private  String mFilename;
private  String mFileSize;
private  String mFileUrl="";
private volatile Integer mProgress;
private volatile ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Integer mFilePercent;
    private String mFileType;
    private Integer mSize;

    public DownloadInfo(String filename, String FileUrl, String size, String type) {
        mFilename = filename;
        mProgress = 0;
        mFileUrl = FileUrl;
        mFilePercent=0;
        mSize = 0;
        mFileType= type;
        mFileSize = size;
        mProgressBar = null;
    }

    public ProgressBar getProgressBar() {
        return mProgressBar;
    }
    public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setProgressBar " + mFilename + " to " + progressBar);
        mProgressBar = progressBar;
    }

    public void setDownloadState(DownloadState state) {
        mDownloadState = state;
    }
    public DownloadState getDownloadState() {
        return mDownloadState;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return mProgress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        this.mProgress = progress;
    }


    public String getFileType() {
        return mFileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(String FileType) {
        mFileType = FileType;
    }
    public Integer getSize() {
        return mSize;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer FSize) {
        mSize = FSize;
    }
    public String getFileSize() {
        return mFileSize;
    }

    public void setFileSize(String FileSize) {
        mFileSize = FileSize;
    }


    public Integer getFilePercent() {
        return mFilePercent;
    }

    public void setFilePercent(Integer FilePercent) {
        mFilePercent = FilePercent;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return mFilename;
    }
    public String getFileUrl()
    {
        return mFileUrl;
    }
}
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter class you set:

```
info.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.QUEUED);
```

It means that on the next getView call you will run downloading of the file even if it was dowloaded before because you reseting the state.

You could check the state in the adapter not in the AsyncTask.

Comment: ok. I removed this from adapter "info.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.QUEUED);"

and I added this condition in the adapter

 "if(info.getDownloadState()!= DownloadInfo.DownloadState.COMPLETE || info.getDownloadState()!= DownloadInfo.DownloadState.DOWNLOADING)
        {
            info.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.QUEUED);
            FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(info);
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }"


The same thing is happening

Comment: Ok, I wrote this in my ArrayAdapter and it's working now..

"if(info.getDownloadState()!= DownloadInfo.DownloadState.COMPLETE && info.getDownloadState()!= DownloadInfo.DownloadState.DOWNLOADING) { info.setDownloadState(DownloadInfo.DownloadState.QUEUED); FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(info); task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); }"


Thanks a lot